# "No Backup account is currently storing data"?

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-3, 4.4-kitkat

When I checked backup & restore options in my settings it shows "No Backup account is currently storing data"  , but I'm currently signed in to my Google account. Why it is disabled?

[image]

(*Click on Image to See large preview*)

Comment: Sorry this might sound silly but did you turn it on when you first logged on? It's usually on by default, but some ROMs have it disabled by default. It can also conflict as some ROMs appear as a new device on your account and it has, in the past for me, caused this to happen. Frankly (and this is not a popular opinion) I find CyanogenMod riddled with issues on any Samsung device.

Comment: I checked this by reinstalling my ROM and also selected backup to This account option. And while I'm searching lots of Nexus devices also reported same issue.

Comment: It is working for me on Nexus 4, Galaxy S4 and Galaxy S4 Google Edition. 2 of them are running 4.4.2 ROMs, none running stock. My first bet is CyanogenMod to be honest. I've tried it and used to love it, the Samsung builds are very, very patchy especially CM 11 which to me, isn't even a beta build yet. I'd try another ROM to confirm/refute this, and proceed from there.

Answer (score 1):

The *backup transport* is the part of the system that takes backed-up data from the phone and sends it to some provider's backup storage. This is a manufacturer- and carrier- replaceable component, to allow (for example) Samsung to make their phones backup to Samsung storage with a Samsung account, instead of backing up to Google, while remaining compatible with apps that use the Android backup system.

Possibly the Cyanogenmod ROM you've installed simply doesn't have a backup transport.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add some more details.

I am using Galaxy Nexus with CM11 Snapshot M4 (latest available) and still have this issue. This issue was present from the first CM11 build which I have installed in this device.

Out of curiosity I have checked couple of Nexus devices and this is what I could find.

1. Nexus 4 - Upgraded to stock 4.4.2 - Doesn't have this issue
2. Nexus 5 - Stock 4.4.2 - Issue is present.

In accordance with Dan's answer above, Since the backup transport is a manufacturer/carrier customizable component, in CyanogenMod it may be a reason. In CM, at the time of device setup, it asks for an optional CyanogenMod account (which I didn't create) and they may be using this CM account for app data backup (not sure, yet to verify this).

Comment: Checked with Paranoid Android 4.1 beta 1 and there isn't any issue in it. It displays my gmail account as backup account.